# How do you test for the existence of a user in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I'd like to drop a user in a SQL Server script but I'll need to test for existence first or I'll get script errors.  When dropping tables or stored procs, I check the sysobjects table like so:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM   sysobjects 
    WHERE  id = object_id(N'[dbo].[up_SetMedOptions]') 
    AND    OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1
)
Drop Procedure up_SetMedOptions;
GO
```

What is the corollary for checking for a user?  Note that I am NOT asking about a database login to the server!  The question pertains to a User in a specific database.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

SSMS scripts it in the following way:

For SQL 2005/2008 and later:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'username')
DROP USER [username]
```

For SQL 2000:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysusers WHERE name = N'username')
EXEC dbo.sp_revokedbaccess N'username'
```

Comment: How to run this on Azure SQL. above quires not working

Comment: @CodeMind - the first query works fine for me on Azure SQL database. In what way is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL 2005:

```
select * from sys.sysusers
```

In SQL 2000:

```
select * from sysusers
```

Answer (score -1):

The code below worked for me.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins WHERE name = N'MyUserName') 
DROP LOGIN [MyUserName]
```

Comment: The question specifically says "I am **NOT** asking about a database **login** to the server".  Your solution will remove a **login** and leave an orphaned database **user**.