# What is the best way to check for the existence of a Login in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am looking for the best way to check that a database login exists in SQL Server 2005. I am currently using

```
IF suser_sid('loginname') IS NOT NULL
```

but suser_sid() returns a value in some cases where a login does not exist.

In SQL 2000 we use

```
SELECT * FROM [Master].[dbo].[sysxlogins] WHERE [name] ='loginname'
```

but that table does not exist in SQL 2005.

There is a similar question about [checking the existence of Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356000), which is helpful, but I am looking for the existence of Logins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sql2005...

```
select * from master.sys.syslogins WHERE [name] ='loginname'
```

Answer (score 0):

`syslogins` is not recommended by Microsoft. It's better to use `sys.server_principals`.

```
select * from sys.server_principals where name = 'login_name'
```