# Drop User from SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-management

How can I drop user from a database without dropping it's logging?

The script should check if the user exists in database, if does then drop the user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you test for the existence of a user in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356000/how-do-you-test-for-the-existence-of-a-user-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do??

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'username')
DROP USER [username]
```

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio you can browse to the user and right-click selecting delete.

Comment: what is the N in here N'username' ?

Comment: The 'n' is just telling sql server that the string value is unicode.  This may prevent problems for people working in various character sets.

Comment: Apparently I found this on 9/23/2019  and again today 9/7/2021  (now I know why I dont ever memorize things, I can just google them :)  Thanks again for second time, cant upvote you again though.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is working good enough. Additionally that is good to know SQL Server added **IF EXIST** to some DROP commands from version 2016 (13.x) including '**DROP USER**' command.

> IF EXISTS
>
> **Applies to**: SQL Server ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x) through current version, SQL Database).
>
> Conditionally drops the user only if it already exists.

So you could just delete user as below:

```
-- Syntax for SQL Server and Azure SQL Database  
DROP USER IF EXISTS user_name
```

See the full description in this link: [DROP USER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Hope this help.

Comment: Older answers are not incorrect, but this is the cleanest and most concise method with 2016+.

Comment: ```DROP USER IF EXISTS 'DOMAIN\user-name'``` returns "Incorrect syntax - expecting ID or QUOTED_ID" .. How to resolve this please?

Comment: DROP USER IF EXISTS [DOMAIN\user-name] use [ ] instead of ' '
also
ALTER LOGIN [DOMAIN\user-name] DISABLE