# Get list of SQL owner and users in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, azure, security

[result of vulnerability assessment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXMJv.png)

I want to identify the users and their permissions to the SQL database and remove users and their permissions from unnecessary access. Do share if there are other alternatives to the resolve these vulnerabilities.

Currently I'm using the SQL query:

```
select *
from sys.sysusers
```

Which displays all the permissions but not the users assigned to the permission

Comment: Don't use images, add to the question as text so we can view it.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `dbo.sysusers` anymore either, it's for compatibility with SQL Server **2000** databases (per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysusers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)). Update to the new system tables: [Mapping System Tables to System Views (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/mapping-system-tables-to-system-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input and edits to the query. Will implement in future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52371316/3844277 
Run following query in SSMS:

```
SELECT
u.name AS [Name],
'Server[@Name=' + quotename(CAST(
        serverproperty(N'Servername')
       AS sysname),'''') + ']' + '/Database[@Name=' + quotename(db_name(),'''') + ']' + '/User[@Name=' + quotename(u.name,'''') + ']' AS [Urn],
u.create_date AS [CreateDate],
u.principal_id AS [ID],
CAST(CASE dp.state WHEN N'G' THEN 1 WHEN 'W' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS [HasDBAccess]
FROM
sys.database_principals AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS dp ON dp.grantee_principal_id = u.principal_id and dp.type = 'CO'
WHERE
(u.type in ('U', 'S', 'G', 'C', 'K' ,'E', 'X'))
ORDER BY
[Name] ASC
```